# Typescript type aliases allow optional interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface, type-alias

I'm trying to create a new type in my typescript code like this:

```
interface required {
  x: string
}

interface optional1 {
  y: string
}

interface optional2 {
  z: string
}

type combined = required & (optional1 | optional2)
```

The behavior I want is:

- the properties of the required interface should definitely be present.
- If there are additional properties, they must comply to either optional1 or optional 2

Comment: What problems are you having with the definition you've come up with?

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark the properties in the optional interfaces as optional, by using a `?` on them.

If you do that, your definition works, other than that an object is allowed to have **both** `y` and `z` properties (that's also true of `type combined = (required & optional1) | (required  & optional2);`, which surprised me):

```
interface required {
  x: string
}

interface optional1 {
  y?: string               // Note the ?
}

interface optional2 {
  z?: string               // Note the ?
}

type combined = required & (optional1 | optional2);

function foo(x: combined): void {

}

foo({ x: "x" });                 // Works
foo({ x: "x", y: "y" });         // Works
foo({ x: "x", y: "y", z: "z" }); // Works
foo({ x: "x", q: "q" });         // Error because of q
foo({ y: "y" });                 // Error because there's no x
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20required%20%7B%0A%20%20x%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20optional1%20%7B%0A%20%20y%3F%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20optional2%20%7B%0A%20%20z%3F%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20combined%20%3D%20required%20%26%20(optional1%20%7C%20optional2)%3B%0A%0Afunction%20foo(x%3A%20combined)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Afoo(%7B%20x%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D)%3B%0Afoo(%7B%20x%3A%20%22x%22%2C%20y%3A%20%22y%22%20%7D)%3B%0Afoo(%7B%20x%3A%20%22x%22%2C%20y%3A%20%22y%22%2C%20z%3A%20%22z%22%20%7D)%3B%0Afoo(%7B%20x%3A%20%22x%22%2C%20q%3A%20%22q%22%20%7D)%3B%0Afoo(%7B%20y%3A%20%22y%22%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: @MuratKaragöz - No, `foo({ x: "x" });` doesn't work with the OP's code, but his requirements say **if** there are other properties, suggesting that that case needs to work.

Comment: This is great! But the problem with it is if I have multiple items in the interface. For an example 
`foo({ x: "x" , y: "y"})` 
still works even if interface optional1 has values: `{ y1:string, y2:string }`

Comment: @HassanNaqvi - Yeah, I see what you mean. I tend to think `foo` needs to be separate functions. :-)